# Python Selenium on Docker extend java.net.http.HttpTimeoutException

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver

Good morning to everybody.

To perform my Selenium tests, I'm using Selenium with Python via Docker container.

The latest script that I'm testing on the same site as many others, freezes the browser page for a few minutes, to the point that I can only scroll through it, being unable to click anything or open the browser's developer tools and after 6 minutes, I got the exception "Unable to execute request for an existing session: java.net.http.HttpTimeoutException: request timed out"

Do you know a way to extend this java.net.http.HttpTimeoutException ?